# Run app on registered IPhone from another computer

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have developers license and able to run apps on my iPhone.
Is it possible to register friends iPhone remotely to my account and to run apps on his device from his computer without having developer license?

Comment: Yes, you create an Ad-Hoc profile with your friend UDID in the profile and send then the app. Or use a service like crashlytics Beta of Apple's TestFlight.